# the color on the css file doesn't work

Tags: html, css, colors

this is my `style.css` file content.

style.css

```
a {color:green; text-decoration: none;}
h1 {font-family: helvetica;}
```

this is my index html file.

```
<html>
<head>


<title>
Test1
</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>

<body>
<h1> My Website </h1>

<p>

visit me on facebook, press 
<a href="http://facebook.com" > 
hereeee please.
</a> . thank you.
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

and the location of the css file is in a folder called css right in the same directory (folder) as the index.html file.
they are all in a desktop folder called learning, inside of it, is the index.html file and a folder called css that has the file style.css in it.
please help it's my first week of self learning HTML. and I'm stuck.
for some reason the font is changing normally but the color and text decoration isn't

Comment: The link to the stylesheet should be in the `<head>` of your document...not in the <`body>`

Comment: add `<!DOCTYPE html>` before `<html>`

Answer (score 1):

```
    Link of the style should be in head.
    it is working:
```

[js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qffz3tyk/)

```
<head>
  <title>  Test1    </title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
</head>
```

Comment: did you checked the demo.

Comment: check your href link. Is your css file is at defined place. I think i may be a problem also.

Comment: yes, I even put the css file in the same folder as the index.html file and I removed the forward slash and the folder name css from the root in the href location but still the font was changed normally to Helvetica but the color and text decoration didn't.

Answer (score 0):

look below is the HTML Basic Examples code need to be followed

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>

    <h1>My Website</h1>

    visit me on facebook, press <a href="http://facebook.com" > hereeee please.</a> . thank you.

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to place your reference to your stylesheet within the head tag. like so

```
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
</head>
```

```css
a {color:green; text-decoration: none;}
h1 {font-family: helvetica;}
```

```html
<h1> My Website </h1>

<p>visit me on facebook, press <a href="http://facebook.com">hereeee please.</a>. thank you.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit index.html code like this

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <title>  Test1    </title>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    </head>

    <body>
       <h1> My Website </h1>

       <p>   
       visit me on facebook, press 
       <a href="http://facebook.com" >    hereeee please.   </a> . thank you.
       </p>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: same problem. I'm going crazy. :O

Comment: @OldGeorge Try this `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" />`